# Crossword clue from today

Tags: cryptic-clues, crossword-clues

A splendid clue from today's "London Times" crossword:

> One my Dr's treated? (8)

Bonus point if you know the technical name for this kind of clue!

Comment: Just edited my answer to include the technical name before seeing your edit :-)

Comment: Why is it always the "London Times" and not the "English Times" or "British Times"? The newspaper itself, and all its readers, call it the Times.

Comment: Good question: I say “London Times” because it’s the common term, but I agree it’s not accurate. Quote from Wikipedia: The Times is the first newspaper to have borne that name, lending it to numerous other papers around the world, such as The Times of India and The New York Times. In countries where these other titles are popular, the newspaper is often referred to as The London Times or The Times of London, although the newspaper is of national scope and distribution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution:

> SYNDROME. It's an &lit clue, being an anagram of "One my Dr's" and also a thing treated by doctors.

Comment: Btw, looks like they [reused this clue](https://times-xwd-times.livejournal.com/1794661.html) from a couple of months ago :-)

Comment: Actually the London Times crossword appears in my local newspaper a couple of months after the original. It takes a "slow boat" or something. That does mean I can't participate in the "Times for the Times" forum